# What is the exact syntax for chmod?

Tags: chmod

I want to give the file OpenRocket-13.11.1.jar  executable permission by using chmod.
So what has gone wrong with this command:

```
 /HomeFolder/Downloads chmod +x OpenRocket-13.11.1.jar
```

It says no such directory or file found.
Is there a problem with my Directory name?

Comment: Where is your OpenRocket-13.11.1.jar exactly?

Comment: it's inside the home folder ,in downloads.Do you need something more specific?

Comment: Question far from being clear. Try to `cd` into the holding directory and do: `chmod [ugoa]+x OpenRocket-13.11.1.jar`. Choose which of user (u), group (g), others (o) or all (a) you want to bless with execute privilege. (I guess that u is in, but perhaps some else too).

Comment: What is the exact error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make some file executable you should use

```
chmod +x <path_to_your_file>
```

However here you are executing a `.jar` file.  so you  can also  execute it with the help of `java` like this

```
java -jar  <path_to_your_jar_file>
```

Comment: how exactly do I specify the path to my file. As far as I can see something went wrong over there.(I am a novice in this since i have never actually written a path name)

Comment: @user235315 something like `~/Downloads/OpenRocket-13.11.1.jar`

Comment: where exactly your jar file is? If it  is in your Downloads directory which is inside your home folder, you can use `chmod +x ~/Downloads/OpenRocket-13.11.1.jar` or  `java -jar ~/Downloads/OpenRocket-13.11.1.jar`

Comment: Also [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/518260/256099) is helpful for symbolic notation & use of octal